# TYPO3 TCA selectCheckBox not working with extension femanager

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, extbase, typo3-9.x

I've created a selectCheckBox in TYPO3 like this:

```php
'region' => [
    'exclude' => true,
    'label' => 'LLL:EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_myext_domain_model_catalog.region',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'select',
        'renderType' => 'selectCheckBox',
        'items' => [
            ['LLL:EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_myext_domain_model_catalog.region.1', 1],
            ['LLL:EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_myext_domain_model_catalog.region.2', 2],
            ['LLL:EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_myext_domain_model_catalog.region.3', 3],
            ['LLL:EXT:myext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_myext_domain_model_catalog.region.4', 4],
        ],
    ],
],
```

When I save it, the database has the comma separated IDs as value like:

`1,3,4`

Now I want to get the value in frontend via the femanager extension.

I've created this configuration for it:

```php
/**
 * region
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $region = [];

/**
 * Returns the region
 *
 * @return array $region
 */
public function getRegion()
{
    return $this->region;
}

/**
 * Sets the region
 *
 * @param array $region
 * @return void
 */
public function setRegion($region)
{
    $this->region = $region;
}
```

Database Configuration:

`region varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,`

But when I try to debug the output like this:

`<f:debug>{catalog.region}</f:debug>`

It just says this:

`array(empty)`

So my `getRegion` function isn't working. Can somebody please give me a hint why it isn't getting the values.

Comment: if you debug the {catalog} variable, is the region key present?

Comment: @AristeidisKaravas no it isn't

Comment: are you extending any other domain model? fe_users or sth?

Comment: My catalogcontroller extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController

Answer (score 1):

`$region` is declared to be an `array` and your setter `setRegion()` is expecting an `array` as parameter. But the stored value in the database is a `varchar`. So, the mapping of the database record on your model will fail for this property.

---

This is working with your TCA:

```
/**
 * @var string
 */
protected string $region = '';

/**
 * @return array
 */
public function getRegion(): array
{
    return GeneralUtility::intExplode(',', $this->region, true);
}

/**
 * @param mixed $region
 */
public function setRegion($region): void
{
    $this->region = (is_array($region) ? implode(',', array_filter($region, 'is_int')) : $region);
}
```

Comment: so my setter should be "string"?

Comment: It depends... The simplest way would be handling it as a string (comma separated list) and splitting the string in your getter. If your regions have more than just a title/label, then maybe an own model and using an objectStorage would be more useful (There's a German blog post by Oliver: http://www.oliver-weiss.com/blog/einzelansicht/article/relationen-in-typo3-teil-3-mn-relation/News/detail/)

Comment: Ty, the changes to string will only work when i update my tca as well, so the backend would handle it like as string too. But i was fine with the backend view and only wanted to change the fronted getter/setter is there a way to change it without affecting the backend view/tca?

Comment: You don't need to change the TCA, just your model. Your model expects currently an array, but your TCA is saving a string. Passing a string to an array-property does not work - except, your setter handles this.  The setter should have `@param string $region` and `$this->region = explode(',', $region);`.

Comment: but when i set it to string it still doesen‘t, but when i change the tca from  ´select´ to ´string´ It works…

Comment: After flushing the caches it should work. I added some working code above.